# How do you translate "spurious" adverbs?

Tags: translation

In German, sentences like these are all [too common](https://www.faz.net/aktuell/sport/mehr-sport/dhb-trennt-sich-nach-em-von-bundestrainer-christian-prokop-16620846.html):

> **Noch** während der EM **zuletzt** bekam er eine Jobgarantie. Nun muss der
>   umstrittene Handball-Bundestrainer Christian Prokop doch gehen.

Without the 'noch' and the 'zuletzt', the passage lends itself to a natural-sounding translation:

> He got a job guarantee during the European Championship. Now the
>   controversial national handball coach Christian Prokop must go.

I am guessing 'noch' here means 'gerade' (because 'still', 'yet' etc don't make sense), but how does 'zuletzt' work here?

> He only got a job guarantee **in the end** during the European
>   Championship.

Which sounds very strange.

Comment: All too common? As a native speaker, I don't even understand what that part is supposed to mean. After reading the answers, I would say that the correct word order should be "Zuletzt noch währen der EM ..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply because some of the other answers either lose the style of the quote or interpret the *noch* and *zuletzt* incorrectly (in my opinion), here is my suggestion.

> As recently as the last EM he was guaranteed a job. Now, however, the controversial handball coach Christian Prokop must go.

As can be seen by the translation, *noch* in this case refers to the continuation of a state up until a certain, past event, as in *noch gestern*, or *letztes Jahr noch*. @DavidVogt describes this well in his answer. Like discussed elsewhere, the postponed *zuletzt* refers to the *EM*, and describes it as the last, most recent *EM*.

Answer (score 5):

My translation is:

> Having received a job guarantee as late as during the last EM, ... has to leave now nevertheless.

*Noch während ...* is the same construct as *noch gestern*, which DeepL translates with *only yesterday*. I don't share the reservations concerning the use of *still* made in another comment.

*Noch* prepares the announcement, that situation has changed now and (according to the writer) quite fast. *Noch/nun* is used similarly to *zwar/aber* in the example above; so *noch* actually carries meaning here.

I don't see the benefit of *zuletzt*; I guess it means, that similiar assertions have been made earlier.

Answer (score 4):

1. The postponed *zuletzt* has already been explained. German lacks an elegant way of saying *recent*. The alternative

> die kürzlich stattgefundene EM

is a mouthful, and sticklers will claim that *stattgefundene* should not be used in this way. Postponed adverbs can substitute:

> die WM zuletzt, kürzlich, neulich

2. In order to capture the meaning that *noch* introduces, one could move away from *while*. Let's look at another example.

> Noch während er im Krankenhaus lag, machte er ihr einen Heiratsantrag.
>   Even before he had been released from hospital, he asked her to marry him.

*While* by itself would not capture the situation well. It is not about contemporaneous events in themselves, but about the violated expectation that the proposal would have to wait.

Since I am not a native speaker, I'm unsure about the more literal translation using *even while*.

> Even while he was  in hospital, he asked her to marry him.

Be that as it may, *even*, not *still*, seems to fit the meaning of *noch* here.

Comment: In your example, "as early as she was ..." would work as well (preferentially after the main clause)

Answer (score 2):

> Noch während der EM zuletzt bekam er eine Jobgarantie. Nun muss der umstrittene Handball-Bundestrainer Christian Prokop doch gehen.

The word "zuletzt" adds context to the abbreviated word "EM" (i.e. "Europameisterschaft" in German or "European Championship" in English) by referring to it as a **recent** event and the word "noch" here could be translated with **still**, indicating that even at that recent event, he was still given a positive signal, i.e. the job guarantee.

So, a possible translation would be:

> During the recent European Championship, he was still given a job guarantee. Now, however, the controversional handball coach Christian Prokop has to leave.

Or, alternatively,

> During the recent European Championship, he still received a job guarantee. Now, however, the controversional handball coach Christian Prokop has to leave.

Comment: I do not agree with your interpretation of the "noch" here. For me (native user of German) the "noch" here is simply a reference to the recency of the events, it does no carry a negative judgement on the justifiability of the action, as "still" would do (at least in my understanding). So, perhaps, "yet" would be a better word to use here.

Comment: @christian-geiselmann, what would be your translation of the full sentence?

Comment: @pbh Perhaps something like "Yet during the recent European Championship he was given a job guarantee." - But keep in mind that I am not a native speaker of English, so I am not totally sure how this sentence feels like.

Answer (score 0):

These kinds of adverbs in German add subtle nuances -- it is particularly recent that his job was guaranteed; hence his leaving now is surprising. English does this not with words, but with intonation.

Think of a sentence like this: "Last week he was being considered for a promotion, and this week he's out the door." The surprise is not in the words or the grammar; it's in the intonation that we all know to put in when we read it -- the clue being the last week/this week contrast.

So translating these German adverbs is not a matter of finding words for them, it's a matter of recognizing the affect that they impart to a statement and reproducing that affect by English means -- by choosing a word order, a sentence structure, etc. that imposes a certain intonation.

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. Please hit the edit button and try to format your text for better readability, like with line breaks or other formatting.